# Find the determinant of dot product entries matrix under $O(k)$ action

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, group-actions

Notation : Here $O(k)$ denotes the orthogonal group, $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Stiefel manifold of $k$ orthonormal-frames and define $\sigma : V_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \times V_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \longmapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\sigma((v_1,\cdots,v_k),(v_1',\cdots v_k')) = \lvert \lvert \text{det}(v_i| v_j')_{i,j=1}^k \rvert \rvert$.

Note that $(v_i| v_j')$
is just a notation for the $ij-th$ element of the matrix, where given two vectors, $(v|w)$ denotes the dot product (in this case the standard one) of vectors $v,w$.

Let's give a right-action of $O(k)$ on $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined as following : given $A = (a_{ij})_{ij} \in O(k)$ we have $(v_1,\cdots,v_k)\cdot A = (w_1,\cdots w_k)$ where $w_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k a_{ij}v_i$

I'd like to prove that $\sigma((v_1,\cdots,v_k)\cdot A),(v_1',\cdots,v_k')\cdot B)) = \sigma((v_1,\cdots,v_k),(v_1',\cdots,v_k'))$, i.e that $\sigma$ factors through $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \times G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I think the trick here is to show that $\sigma((v_1,\cdots,v_k)\cdot A),(v_1',\cdots,v_k')\cdot B)) = \lvert \text{det}(A) \text{det}(B)\rvert \cdot \sigma((v_1,\cdots,v_k),(v_1',\cdots v_k'))$ and then conclude since $ \lvert \text{det}(A) \text{det}(B)\rvert = 1$ since $A,B \in O(k)$.

Unfortunately I'm unable to show the first equality above, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps $\sigma$ would be more clearly expressed as 
$$
\sigma((v_1,\dots,v_k),(v_1',\dots,v_k')) = |\det([(v_i|v_j')]_{i,j = 1}^k)|.
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Edited, should be clearer now, thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to say that $A \in O(k)$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes thanks, editing right now.

Comment: You have incorrectly copied my suggested change in notation in a way makes me think that you might not understand the convention being used here. So to explain a bit: $[a_{ij}]_{i,j = 1}^k$ is a common way to express "the $k \times k$ matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $a_{ij}$". This matrix is in turn put into the determinant function, which is in turn put into the absolute value function. By putting the ${}_{i,j=1}^k$ on the outermost layer of parentheses, you indicate that the output of the function $\sigma$ is a matrix, which is probably not what you want to communicate.

Comment: Also, a tip for this site: if you want to view/copy the Latex for a mathematical expression, you can right click the expression and select "Show Math As" > "TeX Commands".

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes thanks that was clear, my latex mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ denote the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_k$ and $V'$ the matrix whose columns are $v_1',\dots,v_k'$. We can write
$$
\sigma((v_1,\dots,v_k),(v_1',\dots,v_k')) = |\det(V^TV')|,
$$
where $V^T$ denotes the transpose of $T$. Similarly, if $(v_1,\cdots,v_k)\cdot A = (w_1,\cdots w_k)$ and $W$ denotes the matrix whose columns are $w_1,\dots,w_k$, then
$$
W = VA.
$$
With that, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma((v_1,\cdots,v_k)\cdot A),(v_1',\cdots,v_k')\cdot B)) &= 
|\det[(VA)^T(V'B)]| 
\\ & = |\det[A^T(V^TV')B]|
\\ & = |\det A^T| \cdot |\det (V^TV')| \cdot |\det B|
\\ & = |\det(V^TV')| = 
\sigma((v_1,\cdots,v_k)),(v_1',\cdots,v_k'))),
\end{align}
$$
which was what we wanted.